# Button subtitle label

Tags: swift, button

One day i did button with title label, subtitle label and image in storyboard and got this effect

[Image of button in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wYbY.png)

but now when i am trying to do this in code programmly i have a problem, i dont see subtitle..

```
private var firstPaidPack: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "circle")
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.3)
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("1.99$", for: .normal)
        button.subtitleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        button.subtitleLabel?.text = "subtitle text to check how it..."
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: screenWidth / 375 * 19)
        return button
    }()
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a `UIButton.Configuration` and set the `subtitle` on the `configuration` object:

```
var config = UIButton.Configuration.tinted()
config.subtitle = "subtitle text to check how it..."
// Set title and all other properties on the configuration object...
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.configuration = config
```

You can also set the `title` and all other properties on the `configuration` object instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below tricks will help you to change the subtitle of the button.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    button.configuration?.subtitle = "Your Subtitle"
}
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73924840) for a detailed answer.