# Problem changing the subtitle in the button

Tags: swift, uikit

I created a button through storyboard title and subtitle, the problem is when I change the name of the subtitle with .subtitleLabel?.text, and then when I click the button, the old value of the subtitle (what was defined in the storyboard) returns.

I would appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should change the subtitle using the button's [`configuration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/3784627-configuration) property instead.

```
button.configuration?.subtitle = "Changed Subtitle"
```

The subtitle is added in iOS 15, as part of the `UIButton.Configuration`. The `configuration` is what actually stores the "true" subtitle of the button, and the `subtitleLabel` just displays it.

When you set the subtitle in the storyboard, you are setting `configuration.storyboard`.